# Cannot access resources defined in EAR from the outside classes (JBoss 5.1)

Tags: java, jboss

I have a resource file located in WAR file stored inside of EAR.

The location is, to be precise: myApp-web.ear/myApp.war/WEB-INF/classes/file.properties.

I'm trying to access this file from another class located in JAR file (not within the main EAR).

This is how I'm trying to access the file:

```
SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/file.properties");
```

The result is null.

This used to work well in JBoss 4.2, but does not work in 5.1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This should never have worked. `WEB-INF/classes/` is already part of the classpath, so `getResourceAsStream("/file.properties")` is the correct way to locate the file.